# Very Simple RScript Cronjob Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, server, cron, r

I have been trying to get a very simple R script (RScript) to run every minute by employing a cronjob; I am on an Ubuntu 16.04 server.  The R script reads an integer between 0-59 from 1 .csv, increments it by 1, and then writes it to an output .csv.  So there are three files:

1. simpleRScript.R
2. input.csv
3. output.csv

simpleRScript.R

```
 # simpleRScript.R
     temp_output <- read.csv("output.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
     input <- read.csv("input.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
     output <- input$value[which(input$value == temp_output$value[1])+1]
     if(output == 60, output <- 0)
     write.csv(output, file = "output.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

input.csv

```
 value,
 0,
 1,
 2,
 ...,
 59
```

output.csv

```
 value,
 0
```

I stored these three files in a folder, cronTest such that they are in:

```
 /home/ubuntu/cronTest
```

Then in the command line, I did the following:

```
 #
 crontab -e
```

And then at the bottom, I typed:

```
 * * * * * RScript /home/ubuntu/cronTest/simpleRScript.R
```

So why when I type:

```
 less output.csv
```

do I not see an incremented value every minute?

Thank you for helping me set up my first RScript cronjob!

Comment: Since you don't appear to `cd` to `/home/ubuntu/cronTest/`, how does `RScript` know where to find `input.csv` and `output.csv`?

Comment: Thank you steeldriver  does that mean I need to type     /home/ubuntu/cronTest/RScript in the cronjob?

Comment: Try changing the crontab command to `cd /home/ubuntu/cronTest/ && RScript simpleRScript.R` or `cd /home/ubuntu/cronTest/ && /path/to/RScript simpleRScript.R` if `Rscript` itself is not in cron's (very limited) search path

Comment: So steel driver that was it:  here's what I typed

     * * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/cronTest/ && /usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript simpleRScript.R

That worked!

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER (thanks to steeldriver in comments)**

Change the cronjob command to

```
 * * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/cronTest/ && /usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript simpleRScript.R
```

**For R users, the Rscript command on ubuntu 16.04 LTS when installed is /usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript**